# Finding a basis and the dimension of $W_1\cap W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $W_1,W_2$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$. $W_1$ is spanned by $(1,2,3,4),   (2,1,1,2)$ and $W_2$ is spanned by $(1,0,1,0),(3,0,1,0)$. I have to find a basis for $W_1\cap W_2$.

I have calculated basis and dimension for $W_1+W_2$, by row-reducing the matrix whose rows are these four spanning vectors. I have found that $\dim(W_1+W_2)=3$. So it follows the dimension of $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=1$. But how do I find a basis for it? My textbook provides a long method, by first finding a homogenous system and row-reducing the corresponding matrix. Is there a shorter way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to close your eyes and write down a nonzero vector that you can show is in both vector spaces.  Since you know the space is one-dimensional, this will be your basis. It's always better to be lucky than good.

This is not as ridiculous as it sounds; you know the vector must have $0$ in the second and fourth coordinates.  Hence a reasonable guess is $(1,2,3,4)-2(2,1,1,2)=(-3,0,1,0)$.  Now if this happens to be in the second vector space, you are done.  And, in fact, $(-3,0,1,0)=3(1,0,1,0)-2(3,0,1,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for answer , but why you have subtracted one vector minus twice of other

Comment: One answer is because I need a linear combination of the basis of $W_1$ that has a zero in the second and fourth coordinates.  The second answer is that 2 is twice 1, and 4 is twice 2, so this particular linear combination will get me what I need.

Comment: The vector is inboth w1 and w2 but how can one be sure that it spans it ,

Comment: Because you have proven that this space ($W_1\cap W_2$) is one-dimensional.

Comment: It can span vectors which areintegral  multiples of 3 in 1st coordinate , what about other vectors say ( 2,0,1,0 )

Comment: That vector is not in $W_1\cap W_2$.

Comment: How can you say that without checking

Comment: Because $W_1\cap W_2$ is one-dimensional, hence exactly $\{k(-3,0,1,0):k\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: I have written 1 vector , so it is 1 dimensional

Comment: The vector $(2,0,1,0)$ is not in the one-dimensional subspace $W_1\cap W_2$, which is the space you are trying to find a basis for.

Comment: @vadim123 the vector (-3,0,1,0) doesnot cover the W_1, so how can it be in basis for intersection of w_1 and w_2 ?

Comment: I mean how will the intersection of two subspaces look like in this case?

Comment: @J.Deff, you are posting a comment to something from five years ago.  The answer to your question is: both $W_1$ and $W_2$ are two-dimensional.  Their intersection is probably one-dimensional.  It might be two-dimensional (if $W_1=W_2$, which is false), or it might be zero-dimensional (if $W_1\cap W_2$ contains only the zero vector, which is also false).

Comment: but w_1 has element which is not 0 at 2nd and 4 th place..so how does this basis vector will span that?

Comment: I was going to type this very question and found this asked

Comment: This vector spans part of $W_1$, not all of $W_1$.